# Conditional variable define in Makefile with ifeq

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

I am trying to define variables in a Makefile, according to conditions. As ifeq can be run only in rules, I have added an additional rule (def_rule) I refer to for each rule.

Example:

```
def_rule:
ifeq ($(TARGET), android)
    CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
else
    echo "native build" 
endf

all:    def_rule tp xi_eid_chipset.o
```

Unfortunately, invoking make all returns this:

> ifeq (linux, android)
>   /bin/sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
>   make: *** [def_rule] Error 2

I cannot figure out why. I have just followed examples in GNU Make documentation.

Do you know how to do conditional defines in Makefiles ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Conditionals can be outside of rules:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET), android)
 $(info Android)
 CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
else
 $(info native build)
 CC=something else
endif
```

(Note that I've tossed in a few leading spaces, just to make it easier to read-- they are neither necessary nor harmful.)

Comment: what does info do?

Comment: @red888: It prints its argument(s) to standard output. Docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions).

Comment: @Beta -- I had a question about your leading spaces: am I correct that the leading spaces must specifically *not be* tabs? When I try to construct a similar `ifeq`-block, my editor (vim) tries to indent the next line (after the `ifeq`-line) with a leading tab. But running `make` on that Makefile seems to fail because (I think) make is interpreting the leading tab to mean a recipe. (I think this could very well be that my vim rules are set not quite right: presumably, it should only indent-with-tab if the preceding line is a rule, not a global condition)

Comment: @StoneThrow: You are correct (about the leading spaces).