# How do I implement this Makefile fail-if-not-true logic in CMake?

Tags: cmake, makefile

I've written a Makefile that enforces (fails if not true) that certain environment variables are set, based on what I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524573/5437543). I settled on using Makefile global conditionals because of what I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77768027/5437543):

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
  ifndef LIBUV
    ifeq ($(shell uname), Windows_NT)
      ifndef VCPKG_DIR
        $(error must define one of LIBUV or VCPKG_DIR)
      endif
    else
      ifndef PRJ_ROOT
        $(error must define one of LIBUV or PRJ_ROOT)
      endif
    endif
  endif

  ifndef SPA
    ifndef PRJ_ROOT
      $(error must define one of SPA or PRJ_ROOT)
    endif
  endif
endif

.PHONY: all clean

all:
        $(info LIBUV: $(LIBUV))
        $(info VCPKG_DIR: $(VCPKG_DIR))
        $(info SPA: $(SPA))
        $(info PRJ_ROOT: $(PRJ_ROOT))
```

This Makefile requires the user who runs `make` to do so with a desired combination of variables being set, either as environment variables or make variables:

```
$ make
Makefile:9: *** must define one of LIBUV or PRJ_ROOT.  Stop.
$
$ make LIBUV=foo
Makefile:16: *** must define one of SPA or PRJ_ROOT.  Stop.
$
$ make LIBUV=foo SPA=bar # LIBUV=foo SPA=bar make is also okay
LIBUV: foo
VCPKG_DIR:
SPA: bar
PRJ_ROOT:
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$
$ make PRJ_ROOT=baz # PRJ_ROOT=baz make is also okay
LIBUV:
VCPKG_DIR:
SPA:
PRJ_ROOT: baz
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I need to convert my handwritten Makefiles to their CMake equivalent, but I've not been able to figure out how to implement the equivalent of Makefile global conditionals. This was my attempt (at a slightly simplified conditional because I'm newly learning), based on online reading into CMake:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(learn-cmake)

message("Operating System: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")

if(NOT DEFINED LIBUV)
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows_NT")
    if(NOT DEFINED VCPKG_DIR)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "must define one of LIBUV or VCPKG_DIR")
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
```

...but when I run `cmake`, or subsequently, `make`, I don't see any sign that the conditional logic is executed:

```
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Operating System: Linux
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/amenon/dev/scratch
$ make
$
```

My question is: **how can I implement conditional logic in CMake that's functionally equivalent to what you can implement with global conditionals in Makefiles?**

On this topic, unclear to me is: when you implement CMake directives like `if(NOT DEFINED LIBUV)`, where does that conditional statement meant to be "applied": when CMake is parsing CMakeLists.txt, or when the *generated Makefile* is parsed (by `make`)?

---

My goal is that after running `cmake .` running `make` without the variables should fail, the same as what the handwritten Makefile enforces.

Comment: What happens when you run CMake without the environment variable being defined? Try, then you'll know for sure.

Comment: @Friedrich - in the bottom-most code-block, all the environment variables are _unset_, therefore my expectation is that the behavior should be equivalent to where I ran `make` without environment variables/make variables.

Comment: Except you're not using environment variables but CMake variables. You should use `$ENV{LIBUV}`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#environment-variables

Comment: All the cmake commands you write in your CMakeLists.txt are executed by cmake, when you run cmake.  None of them are executed by make (or ninja or visual studio or whatever generator you used).  There is no way to get cmake to generate such a check into the generated build control files so that the error will be detected by make (or ninja or visual studio or whatever).

Comment: Given my previous comment it's useless to check for the _environment variable_ when you run cmake.  Just because it was in the environment when cmake was invoked, doesn't mean it will be available when make is run.  Instead you should have your users provide these values when they run cmake as _cmake variables_, then use cmake variables to inject those values into the build control file.  This does mean that if you want to change these values you have to re-run cmake.

Comment: @MadScientist - you've helped me with other questions, thank you again for your help here. So if I understand your comment correctly: the cmake paradigm is: users provide the variables as _cmake variables_ so that they are defined when cmake is invoked, i.e. the variables are available when cmake is _generating_ Makefiles. Those defined cmake variables will automagically become defined variables _in the generated Makefile_, so when make is invoked, they won't need to be supplied as either make variables or environment variables -- did I understand correctly?

Comment: Mostly, except for the "automagically defined" part.  You don't write makefile rules in CMake (the entire point of CMake is that it can generate control files for many different build tools, make is only one of them, so you can't do "make specific things" in a cmake file).  You have to separate from thinking like a makefile.  CMake is not make. 
 Nothing in your question gives us a hint as to what you want to do with those variables, but presumably you want them to be part of your build in some way; when you define your targets or defines or whatever they should use those cmake variables.